# calculate number of checked checkbox in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to display how many checked checkboxes using this code

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="user in data">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.checked"/>
  {{user.name}}
</li>

<p>total checked: {{user.checked.length}}</p>
```

I also tried count() within the {{}} but doesn't work.

[demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kGRSrq5hCwLGF8jVfTjE?p=preview)

Comment: Try `{{user.checked|length}}` ?

Comment: @Fabien, That won't work

Answer (score 12):

You should filter users by `checked` property:

```
<p>total checked: {{ (data | filter:{checked: true }).length }}</p>
```

Comment: that's neat.  working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Vbp6KfXfqnhAp7KqYUAi?p=preview

Comment: that's smart :) +1 definitely

Comment: Thanks buddy .. I spent hours to find it ... excellent example.

Comment: Three years ago still valid for angular 1.5. A little note, the checkbox must have `ng-model=user.checked` (as it is in plunker) but the key is the attribute **checked**.

Comment: very neat, for ages I've been using ng-change and looping the data. This is much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Markup:

`<p>total checked: {{checkedCount()}}</p>`

Controller:

```
$scope.checkedCount = function(){
  return $scope.data.filter(function(person){
    return person.checked;
  }).length;
}
```

[working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YDkwzwqtncLoYwrJAzEe?p=preview)

Comment: as ryeballer alluded, `Array.filter` isn't supported in IE8.  source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Browser_compatibility

Comment: nice code but I gt this in console Error: [$interpolate:interr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$interpolate/interr?p0=Open%20%7B%7Bchec…pic&p1=TypeError%3A%20Cannot%20read%20property%20'filter'%20of%20undefined

Comment: @user3522729, are you using IE8?

Comment: Do you get that error when viewing the plunker? Or is this in your own code now?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function to calculate all the checked elements inside your **controller**:

```
    $scope.calculateChecked = function() {
      var count = 0;

      angular.forEach($scope.data, function(value) {
        if(value.checked)
          count++;
      });

      return count;
   };
```

and then in your **HTML**

```
 <p>total checked: {{calculateChecked()}}</p>
```

[ASSOCIATE PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Ad7qerU7MMQBZApIhkx?p=preview)

Comment: yes we sure did, your solution is quite beautiful and readable but it won't work on some browser versions.